# OpenLayers: add a listener to a single polygon

Tags: events, google-maps, maps, openlayers-2

I want to add a listener to a single polygon. Currently, I am trying to add one that makes a polygon opaque when you click on it, but I should be able to add any general listener. `OpenLayers.Layer` has an `events` property, but there is no such property for `OpenLayers.Feature` or `OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon`.

This is my setup:

- An `OpenLayers.Layer.Vector` layer, `pLayer`, called `"polygon layer"` that contains all of the polygons.
- A function `handleClick` that sets `this.style.fillOpacity = 1`. `this` is supposed to refer to the polygon clicked on
- For each polygon, I call:

  ```
  pLayer.events.register('click', polygon, handleClick);
  ```

The issue with this setup is that when I click on any of the polygons, it fires the event for all polygons on that layer and every polygon becomes opaque. How do I make it so that the event only fires for individual polygons?

I need this to be general. Basically, I want to be able to add any type of listener to a **single** polygon. My overall goal is to create an interface between **Google Maps** and **OpenLayers**, and I **Google Maps** you can add an event to a single polygon.

Will I need to put every polygon on a separate layer? If that is the case, how do I set up the renderer for each of those polygon layers? Or is there a way to keep all polygons in the same layer and have the event handle each of them individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SelectFeature](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature) to handle the clicks for individual features.

Here's an example:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature.html

Comment: Ok. I guess I'll need to get a little tricky about interfacing with the Google Maps API. That does seem like the best option for selecting polygons, though.

Comment: Both links are now out of date (page not found).